# Calling network services in parallel using RxJava. Is this the right way?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java

Idea is to make 3 network calls in parallel. (I am using Google as the servies for demo purpose. The following works but not sure if this is the right way or it can be simplified. What should I do if I have to combine the responses of all the three searches? Please advise.

```
public class GoogleSearchRx
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);

        search("RxJava").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(
                links -> {
                    links.forEach(link -> out.println(currentThreadName() + "\t" + link.text()));
                    latch.countDown();
                },
                e -> {
                    out.println(currentThreadName() + "\t" + "Failed: " + e.getMessage());
                    latch.countDown();
                }
        );

        search("Reactive Extensions").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(
                links -> {
                    links.forEach(link -> out.println(currentThreadName() + "\t" + link.text()));
                    latch.countDown();
                },
                e -> {
                    out.println(currentThreadName() + "\t" + "Failed: " + e.getMessage());
                    latch.countDown();
                }
        );

        //run the last one on current thread
        search("Erik Meijer").subscribe(
                links -> {
                    links.forEach(link -> out.println(currentThreadName() + "\t" + link.text()));
                    latch.countDown();
                },
                e -> {
                    out.println(currentThreadName() + "\t" + "Failed: " + e.getMessage());
                    latch.countDown();
                }
        );

        try
        {
            latch.await();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Observable<Elements> search(String q)
    {
        String google = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";

        String charset = "UTF-8";
        String userAgent = "ExampleBot 1.0 (+http://example.com/bot)"; // Change this to your company's name and bot homepage!

        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Elements>()
        {

            @Override public void call(Subscriber<? super Elements> subscriber)
            {
                out.println(currentThreadName() + "\tOnSubscribe.call");

                try
                {
                    Elements links = Jsoup.connect(google + URLEncoder.encode(q, charset)).timeout(1000).userAgent(userAgent).get().select("li.g>h3>a");
                    subscriber.onNext(links);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going by the "combine the responses of all the three searches" part of your question, you might be looking for [Zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html).

```
Observable<Elements> search1 = search("RxJava");
Observable<Elements> search2 = search("Reactive Extensions");
Observable<Elements> search3 = search("Eric Meijer");
Observable.zip(searc1, search2, search3,
            new Func3<Elements, Elements, Elements, Elements>() {
                @Override
                public Elements call(Elements result1, Elements result2, Elements result3) {
                    // Add all the results together...
                    return results;
                }
            }
    ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(
            links -> {
                links.forEach(link -> out.println(currentThreadName() + "\t" + link.text()));
                latch.countDown();
            },
            e -> {
                out.println(currentThreadName() + "\t" + "Failed: " + e.getMessage());
                latch.countDown();
            }
    );
```

This assumes you want to deal with all the results at the same time (in the subscriber, here) and not care about which query was used for the given result.

Note there's different versions of the `zip` function, taking from 1..N observables, and `Func1` to `Func9` or `FuncN`, allowing you to zip a specific or arbitrarily large number of observables.

Comment: Hi @AdamS, how to handle the case where one of the call fails/ throws exception?

Comment: This way the second call happens after the first one returns. To fix this, use:
Observable<Elements> search1 = search("RxJava").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());    
Observable<Elements> search2 = search("Reactive Extensions").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());    
Observable<Elements> search3 = search("Eric Meijer").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach which handles the entire process (including the Jsoup call), avoids any countdown latches, and provides a way to avoid having to use `Observable.create` (since it's a lot easier to let the Rx operators handle all the subscriber management stuff!)

("back-of-napkin" code, may need some nudging to compile.)

```
final String google = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";

final String charset = "UTF-8";
final String userAgent = "ExampleBot 1.0 (+http://example.com/bot)"; // ...
Observable.just("RxJava", "Reactive Extensions", "Erik Meijer")
    .flatMap((query) -> Observable.defer(() -> {
        try {
            return Observable.from(Jsoup.connect(google + URLEncoder.encode(query, charset))
                .timeout(1000)
                .userAgent(userAgent)
                .get()
                .select("li.g>h3>a")).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }))
    .forEach(
        (link) -> out.println(link.text()),
        (e) -> out.println("Failed: " + e.getMessage()));
```

Note that, as in your original example, the sorting of this isn't guaranteed. One way to handle that would be `toSortedList`, which either expects an Observable of items implementing `Comparable`, or a `Func2` to provide comparison between elements.

Comment: Why are you using "defer()" as well as Schedulers.io()?

Comment: I'm calling `defer` because `Jsoup.connect` seems like it's a blocking call. `defer` will not run the inner function to create the `Observable` until it is subscribed.

Comment: Subscribing on `io` just means the work done grabbing the request will be done in Rx's thread pool meant for io operations, such as disk access or network calls like this.

Comment: Ok. so if you do not call defer() then the "Jsoup.connect()" is executed immediately? If so does that mean all 3 searches happen one after another instead of concurrently?

Comment: It depends on where `flatMap`'s subscribe work is being done, which you can tweak. If you wanted things to be done explicitly in order, `concatMap` would be a good choice (direct replacement for `flatMap` here), which maintains a `SerialSubscription` and will only subscribe to one incoming observable at a time. However, without the defer in those cases, processing incoming strings to create and buffer the observable to go next would block on the request, so the `defer` actually is nice in the `concatMap` case too.

Comment: @lopar in this case, would `defer` achieve the same result as doing `Observable.just(q).map(q -> Jsoup.doStuff(q))`? (complete noob on rxjava here).